# run angular2 webpack behind a reverse proxy on subpath

Tags: angular, webpack

I want to run `angular2-webpack-starter` behind a apache reverse proxy. Each URL has to begin with a fixed prefix, e.g. `/angular2-webpack-starter/`. I found the following setting:

```
output: {
  publicPath:"angular2-webpack-starter",
  ...
```

Is this the right option to use? Which npm jobs should I use? Websockets will not work over my proxy.

Comment: Any advance on *"does not work"*?

Comment: That's not the ideal attitude to encourage strangers to help you for free. I'd recommend reading [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to angular-cli and run:

```
ng build --prod --base-href /my-path/
```

That works for me.